# How to find federal taxes based on salary ranges

Tags: vb.net

I'm designing a software that does basic payroll for a school project. I'm stuck on this one part where I have to figure out what the federal tax will be based on the employee salary. This is the chart that tells you the rate of the tax based on salary range.
[image]

I tried this code,

```
  Dim federaltaxrate As Integer
            Dim federaltax = (salary.Text * federaltaxrate)
            If salary.Text >= 0 Then
                If salary.Text <= 50 Then
                    federaltaxrate = 0
                End If
            ElseIf salary.text <= 500 Then
                If salary.Text >= 50 Then
                    federaltaxrate = 0.1
                End If
            ElseIf salary.text <= 2500 Then
                If salary.Text >= 500 Then
                    federaltaxrate = 45 + 0.15 * salary.Text - 500
                End If
            ElseIf salary.text <= 5000 Then
                If salary.Text >= 2500 Then
                    federaltaxrate = 345 + 0.2 * salary.Text - 2500
                End If
            ElseIf salary.text >= 5000 Then
                federaltaxrate = 845 + 0.25 * salary.Text - 5000
            End If
            Else

            End If
```

I have a listbox that shows other information as well but this is what I used to show the calculated info in the listbox.

```
 ListBox1.Items.Add("Federal Tax: $" + federaltax.ToString)
```

When I run this code and input in a random salary, the federal tax shows up as 0.
Do I need to convert the salary into weekly gross pay, if so how would I go on about writing the code that finds the federal tax rate based on the salary and it's range.

Comment: You calculate `federaltax` before finding the `federaltaxrate`, so it will always equal 0. Move `Dim federaltax = (salary.Text * federaltaxrate)` to after your `if` statements. Take a look at using breakpoints & the debugger which would allow stepping through this.

Comment: You declare `FederalTaxRate` as an `Integer` but then try to set it to a floating point value.  When you do this, VB will round to the nearest integer, which is 0 for anything less than 0.5.  I'm not sure that this is the primary issue (any salary over 500 will have a nonzero value) and the math looks suspect anyway, but `federaltaxrate` should be either `Decimal` or `Double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be having trouble with order of precedence of the arithmetic operations. I think a Select Case is cleaner.

```
Private Function GetFederalTax(GrossPay As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim FederalTax As Decimal
    Select Case GrossPay
        Case < 50
            FederalTax = 0
        Case < 500
            FederalTax = CDec((GrossPay - 51) * 0.1)
        Case < 2500
            FederalTax = CDec(((GrossPay - 500) * 0.15) + 45)
        Case < 5000
            FederalTax = CDec(((GrossPay - 2500) * 0.2) + 345)
        Case Else
            FederalTax = CDec(((GrossPay - 5000) * 0.25) + 845)
    End Select
    Return FederalTax
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim grossPay As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, grossPay) Then
        Dim tax = GetFederalTax(grossPay)
        Debug.Print($"Gross {grossPay} Tax {tax}")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("Federal Tax {0}, Gross Pay {1}", tax, grossPay)) '***EDIT***
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
    End If
End Sub
```

The sample test produced the following in the Immediate Window.

> Gross 45 Tax 0
>
> Gross 700 Tax 75
>
> Gross 8000 Tax 1595
>
> Gross 2501 Tax 345.2
>
> Gross 2800 Tax 405

Comment: Can  be “Case < 50” removed from the select case?

Comment: No, because it would drop to the next case and produce a negative tax.

Comment: I mean a union (Case > 50 AndAlso Case < 500). However is more clear as you can

Comment: I suppose so but I prefer the consistency of including the `Case < 50`.

Comment: Actually the table provided by the OP has a hole in it between 50 and 51.

Comment: I'm agree with you.It have a more clear visual impact doing as you said

Comment: I tried this and used `listbox1.items.add("Federal Tax: $" + grosspay + tax)` and it showed the federal tax but it was wrong. For example, if I typed in salary as 1, the result would be a negative federal tax. I

Comment: I just ran a test with 1 typed into the text box. Result in Immediate window was `Gross 1 Tax 0`.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: `listbox1.items.add("Federal Tax: $" + grosspay + tax)` With Option Strict on the compiler does not know what to make of this code. grossPay and tax in my code are type Decimal. Are you trying to add these values or change them to strings and concatenate them.

Comment: The dollar sign in my code indicates a interpolated string. This is available in Visual Studio 2015 and later. In earlier version use String.Format

Comment: Thank you so much! I enabled the option strict and tested our code out and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your Boolean logic is all wrong. If the salary value was 51, you'd satisfy the first outer condition (>= 0) and then fail the first inner condition (<= 50).  There would not be any further comparisons performed - which you would know if you'd debugged - so no tax calculation would ever be performed.

Secondly, your calculations are OK but you're misusing the results.  Those calculation get the amount of tax to be paid, not the rate.  The rates are 10%, 15%, 20% and 25%, which are already contained in your calculations.  Get rid of that second variable and just assign the results of appropriate calculations to the one variable.

I would do it like this:

```
Dim salaryAmount = CDec(salary.Text)
Dim taxAmount As Decimal = Decimal.Zero

If salaryAmount > 5000D Then
    taxAmount = 845D + 0.25D * (salaryAmount - 5000D)
ElseIf salaryAmount > 2500D Then
    taxAmount = 345D + 0.2D * (salaryAmount - 2500D)
ElseIf salaryAmount > 500D Then
    taxAmount = 45D + 0.15D * (salaryAmount - 500D)
ElseIf salaryAmount > 50D Then
    taxAmount = 0.1D * (salaryAmount - 50D)
End If

'Use taxAmount here.
```

This uses appropriate data types throughout, i.e. it does not perform arithmetic on `String` values and it uses `Decimal` for currency values.  The `D` suffix on the literals forces them to be type `Decimal` rather than `Integer` or `Double`. 
It also works from biggest to smallest to simplify the Boolean expressions.

Comment: Someone's a bit quick off the mark with the down-vote. Given that the tooltip displayed when you hover over the down-vote arrow says "This answer is not useful", I'd be interested to know exactly what their justification was.

Comment: I tried this method out and `ListBox1.Items.Add("Federal Tax: $" + taxAmount)` but the output in the listbox doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

The Nested If should be combined like below as it is missing few cases

```
     If salary.Text >= 0 And salary.Text <= 50 Then
         federaltaxrate = 0
     ElseIf salary.text <= 500 And salary.Text >= 50  Then                
         federaltaxrate = 0.1                
     ElseIf salary.text <= 2500 AND salary.Text >= 500 Then                   
         federaltaxrate = 45 + 0.15 * salary.Text - 500               
     End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tried nesting the code and the federal tax still returns as 0 in the listbox, regardless of the salary.

Comment: Can you specify the input Salary value you are testing with

Comment: Your last calculation is missing a pair of parnetheses.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes . it was just a example .

Comment: Using the actual values from the question and performing a very close approximation of the actual calculation from the question but doing it incorrectly makes for a bad example.  This also only fixes one of several problems.